# how to get/search users from a domain or a sub-domain in azure ad through graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am newbie/noob to AZURE AD. I have started understanding the AZURE AD Graph API and trying them in postman. I am still exploring things.

Using the AZURE AD Graph API could get the Users, Groups and so on.

- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/
- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/

Here is my question

- Do we have a AZURE AD Graph API to retrieve users from a domain and sub-domain
- Do we have a AZURE AD Graph API to search for an user in a domain and sub-domain

Example : Say the domain name is **avinash.com** and we have sub-domains as **IT** and **Finance**

- How to get/ search for users from avinash.com or IT and Finance ?

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

As the Azure AD graph is integrated with MS graph , you can use You can use the Azure AD APIs in Microsoft Graph to query the user's profile, find other users, manage organizational relationships, track assignments, or create original solutions that incorporate existing organizational data.

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/azuread-identity-access-management-concept-overview#manage-users-and-groups

Graph API to retrieve users from a domain and sub-domain:

[image]

for more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-5-use-filter-to-retrieve-specific-users-based-on-a-property-value

Hope this helps.